# Returning child records in a single SQL statement in SQL Server 2008/2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I currently have the following SQL statement in a Stored Procedure;

```
SELECT [Id],
    [Path],
    [Title],
    [Description]
FROM [Configuration].[Pages] p 
WHERE 
    ((p.Id = @Id) OR (@Id IS NULL)) AND
    ((p.Path = @Path) OR (@Path IS NULL))
```

This allows me to pass in either the path of the page, the id of the page or nothing (to return all).

I am looking to refactor this to return related child records (1 to M) rather than going back in the DB for each record returned. The current SQL for the child records is as follows;

```
SELECT     h.Id, h.Description, h.Title, h.[Content]
FROM            [Configuration].[HelpItems] h INNER JOIN
                         [Configuration].[PageHelpItems] ph ON h.Id = ph.HelpId
WHERE        (ph.PageId = @PageId)
```

At present, I am looping through each of the parent records and calling this Stored Procedure for each, which I believe is inefficient and I would like to have one or more SQL statements with the SP that ensure the child records are returned for all parents.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you useing? SQL Server? Which version? How many levels can the tree recurse dows? Have you heard of recursive CTEs?

Comment: SQL Server 2008/2012. Only a single level of recursion.

Comment: OK, you mentioned "I am not looking to refactor this to return related child records ", is the "not" correct there, you do NOT wish to refactor?

Comment: @astander Well spotted, updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the record

```
;WITH Rec AS (
    SELECT [Id],
        [Path],
        [Title],
        [Description]
    FROM [Configuration].[Pages] p 
    WHERE 
        ((p.Id = @Id) OR (@Id IS NULL)) AND
        ((p.Path = @Path) OR (@Path IS NULL))
)
SELECT 'Main' Which, * FROM Rec
-- plus the children...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Related', h.Id, h.Title, h.Description, h.[Content]
FROM   [Configuration].[HelpItems] h
INNER JOIN [Configuration].[PageHelpItems] ph ON h.Id = ph.HelpId
INNER JOIN Rec ON Rec.Id = ph.PageId
```

Comment: I get the following error when attempting to alter this; All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: Sorry - corrected. I read the columns wrong. For the child records, you will get title under "path", description under "title" and content under "description".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following query:

```
SELECT     h.Id, h.Description, h.Title, h.[Content] 
FROM            [Configuration].[HelpItems] h INNER JOIN 
                     [Configuration].[PageHelpItems] ph ON h.Id = ph.HelpId 
                INNER JOIN [Configuration].[Pages] p ON ph.PageId = p.Id
WHERE     
    ((p.Id = @Id) OR (@Id IS NULL)) AND    
    ((p.Path = @Path) OR (@Path IS NULL))
```

Comment: The problem with this is it will return multiple records for each parent with multiple child records. I was hoping to not have to filter these at the consumer.

Comment: If you will search for a page with PageId or Path it will give the child records of only that parent not for each parent. But if you will not provide either of them then it will return multiple child records for each parent.